# runtime 1004 error, every second time code executes

Tags: vba, excel

I'll try and keep my query simple, I don't think my code is overly relevant.

I have a sub which changes values on a sheet, some of those changes trip worksheet change event listeners. So that is a bit inefficient maybe, but shouldn't cause me any problems.

Here's the rub: Every other time I run my 1st macro - changing values - my worksheet behaves perfectly. Everytime in between, I hit a 1004 runtime error.

When I hit the error I End code execution. Do the same thing again and it works, fails, works, fails etc.

I am thinking there is some VBA or Excel setting that I need to manually clear to avoid the runtime error. but I have no idea what it could be. I could also re-write my procedures to avoid the cells that trigger the event listeners, but I would really like to understand what is going on.

Edit: ok here is some code, I use this to find my list of invoices by customer and display a userform to select the invoice to display:

```
Sub Look_for_invs()
Dim cell, invDB As Range
Dim srch_rng As Range
Set invDB = Range("Invoice_DB")

invDB.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, Range("inv_lookup_crit"), Range("inv_lookup_result"), True

Dim length As Integer
On Error GoTo exerr

length = Int(WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("inv_lookup_result_list").Columns(1)))
Range("inv_lookup_result_list").Cells(1, 1).Offset(length, 0).Value = "NEW"

GoTo exok
exerr:
length = 1
Range("inv_lookup_result").Cells(1, 1).Offset(length, 0).Value = "NEW"
exok:


Set srch_rng = Range("inv_lookup_result_list")

With InvoiceSelection.InvListBox
    .ColumnCount = 4
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .RowSource = "inv_lookup_result_list"
End With

Worksheets("Invoice Entry").Select

InvoiceSelection.Show vbModeless

End Sub
```

Here is the code for the userform, this takes the invoice number and puts the values into my invoice template, it seems to me like I am unable to access members of Range objects while the userform is active. I disabled events since posting the question to try and see if that would help, it didn't:

```
Private Sub InvListBox_Click()
Dim invnum, invitems_cnt, invitem As Integer
Dim accnum As String
Dim inv_arrival, inv_depart As Date
Dim invDB, cell, invoice_lines As Range
Dim inv_ent_sht As Worksheet

With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

invnum = InvListBox.Value
accnum = Range("invoice_ent_account")
Set invDB = Range("Invoice_DB")
Set invoice_lines = Range("invoice_lines")
Set inv_ent_sht = Worksheets("Invoice Entry")

clear_inv_sheet


If invnum <> "NEW" Then
    'set variables
    inv_depart = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(invnum, invDB.Offset(0, 1), 5, False)
    inv_arrival = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(invnum, invDB.Offset(0, 1), 4, False)
    'transfer header-level invoice details to sheet
    Range("inv_inv_num") = invnum
    Range("inv_depart") = inv_depart
    Range("inv_arrival") = inv_arrival

    'find all items relating to invoice lines and move them to invoice lines area of statement
    For Each cell In invDB.Columns(2).Cells
        If cell.Value = invnum Then
            invitem = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(invoice_lines.Columns(1)) + 1
            invoice_lines.Cells(invitem, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 5)
            invoice_lines.Cells(invitem, 2) = cell.Offset(0, 2)
            invoice_lines.Cells(invitem, 5) = cell.Offset(0, 6)
            invoice_lines.Cells(invitem, 6) = cell.Offset(0, 7)
            invoice_lines.Cells(invitem, 7) = cell.Offset(0, 12)
            invoice_lines.Cells(invitem, 8) = cell.Offset(0, 13)
        End If
    Next cell


    'invitems_cnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("invoice_DB").Columns(2), invnum)

End If
InvoiceSelection.Hide
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You worksheet event code is probably running at inappropriate times.  To get better assistance, you will need to **post your code.**

Comment: your code IS RELEVANT. it will tell the whole story as to why you encounter such error. my guess is that you encounter the runtime due to the way you've structured your code. runtime only occurs if you want excel to access something it cannot find or most often than not.

Comment: two thoughts: 1) you probably need another `On Error ...` statement after  `exok:`, else any error occurring below will jump back up 2) If you use `On Error Goto 0`, the debugger will stop in the line where the error occurred. Use this to identify the erroneous line and let us know which one it is!

Answer (score 0):

you might need to re-arrange the data before the vlookup (works only if data is in alphabetical/numeric order).

or, you can maybe use the find function, or match, wich dont need reorganizing the data each time you add cells to it.

You also didn't tell wich line shows the error (hit debug instead of end code).
change the  on error goto exerr, to on error goto 0, so you can find where the code missbehaves.